# Collapse menu doesn't close when I click on toggler button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I build a responsive menu with Bootstrap 4.0.0, the collapse menu opens when I click on it, but it doesn't close when I click on it again.
The code is:

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a href="index.php"><img class="nav-link" src="wp-content\themes\VillanovaTheme\img\home.svg"
            id="homeimage"></a>
    <button id="bottone" class="navbar-toggler js-scroll-trigger" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#1">Luoghi di pregio e personaggi di spicco</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#2">Eventi culturali ed enogastronomici</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#3">Strutture ricettive presenti nel territorio di
                    Villanova di Camposampiero</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#4">Servizi</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#5">Contatti</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The menu toggle [seems to work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/yqkf16zx/). It might help to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have include bootstrap.css, jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js, bootstrap.min.js, popper.min.js

Comment: Please provide your site URL. The code seems error free.

Comment: I use this code for create a theme in wordpress. I'm create this site in localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing jquery and popper.js